# ECS+Fargate のソースコードのマウントについて

Tags: aws, docker, aws-ecr

※本サイト含め3カ所でマルチポストさせていただいております。
https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12274662377
https://teratail.com/questions/uuw328n9imd4ci
[ECS+Fargate のソースコードのマウントについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/93590/)

ECS初学者です。
現在EC2で動いているLAMP環境をECS+Fargateで動かすことを目標としています。

下記の構成で Dockerfile に COPY コマンドを記述し、
ビルドする際にソースコードをコンテナに入れてからECSにプッシュしています。

`COPY ./html /var/www/html`

`docker build -t ecs-demo-web ./docker/web/`

Project
┠docker
┃┗web
┃┃┠Dockerfile
┃┃┗html
┃┃　┗index.php
┃┗db
┃　┗Dockerfile
┗docker-compose.yml

以下のようにDockerfileとソースコードの階層が分かれていることが一般的だと思います。
（現行のアプリケーションも下記の構成です）

Project
┠docker
┃┠web
┃┃┗Dockerfile
┃┗db
┃　┗Dockerfile
┠html
┃┗index.php
┗docker-compose.yml

COPY コマンドは親ディレクトリを参照できないと思うのですが、
COPY コマンドを使わずに、ソースコードをFargateコンテナに乗せる方法があるのでしょうか。

ご回答いただけますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

こちらで回答いただいて解決しました。
https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12274662377

■前者の場合 docker build を使う
`docker build -t web ./docker/web`

■後者の場合 docker compose build を使う
`docker compose build`

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile
```